# SdtContentDropDownList.LastValue Property is Null

Tags: c#, openxml

How to read the selected value of `SdtContentDropDownlist` using OpenXML in C#.
I was trying to read it using `LastValue` but it is always returning `null`.

Comment: Could you give a bit more details ?

Comment: I was trying to read a word.docx file which has SdtContentDropdownlist control. This control will allow us to add dropdownlist in word document. after that I was trying to read this using OpenXML WordprocessingDocument.